# CMake test if i am in scripting mode

Tags: cmake

I would like to use the same cmake file as a script and a include file

do_something.cmake:

```
function(do_something)
   # do something
endfunction

if(CMAKE_IS_SCRIPTING_MODE) # this variable does not exist!
   do_something()
endif
```

This way i can easyly call my scripts from a CMake project and from the shell. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5):

While CMAKE_SCRIPT_MODE_FILE is ok, you cannot simply check if it is set. You may run into problems, when you include this file from a script.

Example:

HelloWorld.cmake

```
include_guard()
function(hello_world)
   message("Hello World")
endfunction()

if(CMAKE_SCRIPT_MODE_FILE)
   hello_world()
endif()
```

script.cmake

```
include(HelloWorld)
hello_world()
```

This will print "Hello World" twice. But you only want to execute `hello_world()` when `HelloWorld.cmake` is the script file.

Therefore you must check if this file is the script file:

```
if(CMAKE_SCRIPT_MODE_FILE MATCHES HelloWorld)
```

or better (because you can copy&paste it):

```
if(CMAKE_SCRIPT_MODE_FILE AND NOT CMAKE_PARENT_LIST_FILE)
```

This way, we check if we are in scripting mode and that we are directly called (not included).

Comment: Sorry for bringing this up, but this elaboration is not reflected in the initial question, and tailoring it into an answer is a bit unfair when viewed in light of my answer provided  more than 2 months ago. Moreover, the documentation quoted clearly states that the **contents** of the variable are set to the full path of the script file, so you can use that as you please in the appropriate tests (as you do), which ends up using  `CMAKE_SCRIPT_MODE_FILE` again.

Comment: Ok, lets say its a different approach. btw: `if(NOT CMAKE_PARENT_LIST_FILE)` would be enough for most cases (even for the original question).

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for [CMAKE_SCRIPT_MODE_FILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SCRIPT_MODE_FILE.html)

> When run in cmake(1) -P script mode, CMake sets this variable to the
>   full path of the script file. When run to configure a CMakeLists.txt
>   file, this variable is not set.